# You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0 directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, rubygems, rbenv

I have a trouble setting up a new environment on a new laptop (mac os).
I have downloaded rbenv, installed 2.7.1 version of ruby, and set the local using `rbenv local 2.7.1`.
When I check the version using `rbenv versions`, I get 'system, *2.7.1' (which I assume that the version 2.7.1 is selected..?)

However, when it comes to downloading rails, `gem install rails` does not exactly do what I want. It only provides an error saying `You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0 directory.` and I guess there is a problem with the directory where the gem is going to be installed. I saw something regarding sudo install is not a great way to resolve this problem, but not really sure how to get through this...

Comment: It looks like you’re rbenv Installation isn’t complete. Can you run `rbenv doctor` and add the output to your question? This command in `rbenv` will evaluate your current environment and make sure everything is installed and configured correctly.

Comment: Did you use sudo while installing ruby with rbenv? Try upgrading your rbenv and run the commands again.

Comment: refer to this link. https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.15-catalina

Comment: What output do you get from `ruby -v`?

Comment: the issue has been resolved after following through the post that Gagan Gupta had provided! thank you!